Trying to solve the energy levels of a spin 1/2 particle in a one-dimensional box using Dirac Equation
I was studying the problem I asked above in the title and found the article P Alberto et al 1996 Eur. J. Phys. 17 19.
The wave function inside the walls is:
$$
\psi(z)=B\ exp(ikz) \left[\begin{array}{c}
                        \chi\\
                        \frac{\hbar k c}{mc^2+E}\sigma_z\chi
                    \end{array}
                \right] + C\ exp(-ikz) \left[\begin{array}{c}
                        \chi\\
                        \frac{-\hbar k c}{mc^2+E}\sigma_z\chi
                    \end{array}
                \right]
$$
The boundary condition is that the flux of probability is zero at the walls:
$$
\pm (i) \gamma^{z} \psi=\psi
$$
Where the $\pm$ sign corresponds to $z=0$ and $z=L$, respectively and $\gamma^z$ is the Dirac gamma matrix. In $z=0$ we found:
$$
C=B\frac{iP-1}{iP+1}
$$
Where P is:
$$
P=\frac{k\hbar c}{E+mc^2}
$$
If we apply the same boundary condition in $z=L$, replacing the relation between B and C previously found, we reach to:
$$
\tan(kL)=\frac{2P}{P^2 -1}
$$
Then, the article said that, using the expression for P in the equation above, we reach to:
$$
\tan(kL)=\frac{2P}{P^2 -1}=-\frac{\hbar k}{mc}
$$
I didn't understand. Following the steps I was able to reach the first equal sign from the equation above, but the second sign is the problem.  As you can see, the RHS of the equation I showed doesn't have a dependence on the eigenvalue $E$. If some of you could help me I'll thank you a lot!

Unfortunately, without more details about what is in the paper, it is not really possible to answer this.

Use the relativistic relationship between energy, momentum, and mass — $E^2-(\hbar kc)^2=(mc^2)^2$ — to express $E$ in terms of $k$ and $m$.

Did you get the algebra to work?
